# JavaScript arrayToList

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

can anyone help me figure what i did wrong in my code? 
Cause I wanna created a function which can help me turn all the array data into list and print the list out.

**Original Instructions**
****Write a function arrayToList that builds up a data structure like the previous one when given [1, 2, 3] as argument, and write a listToArray function that produces an array from a list. Also write the helper functions prepend, which takes an element and a list and creates a new list that adds the element to the front of the input list, and nth, which takes a list and a number and returns the element at the given position in the list, or undefined when there is no such element.
If you haven’t already, also write a recursive version of nth.****

```
function arrayToList(arrayx){
for(var i=10;i<arrayx.length;i+=10)
var list = {
 value: i,
 rest: {
   value: i+=10,
   rest: null}}
return list;
}
```

**The Results I wanna have is**

```
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));

// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Comment: What's the use case of this? It seems way too complicated..

Comment: In that case you need to return an array of objects as list

Comment: as @Erazihel said, i find this really complicated. Could you tell us what's the final usecase of the list ?

Comment: Ohhhh....Well, here is the original contents of the exercise:

Comment: @Okazari I have added some original instructions in the question, Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this as well :

```js
    
    
    function arrayToList(arrayx){ 
    for(var i = arrayx[0];i < Math.max.apply(Math,arrayx); i+=arrayx[0])
    {
     var list = {
     value: i,
     rest: {
     value: i+=10,
     rest: null
       }
      }
    return list;
    }
    }
    
    console.log(arrayToList([10 , 20]));
```

Comment: May I ask what the "Math.max.apply" is?

Comment: To find max value from array. cannot use array.length because as per your e.g your array length will be 2 or 3 but first array element is 10 so loop condition will never satisfy

Comment: will really appreciate if you can upvote and accept it as answer if this helped you

Comment: Sure, i will do that!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // This is a function to make a list from an array
    // This is a recursive function
    function arrayToList(array) {
        // I use an object constructor notation here
        var list = new Object();
        // This is to end the recursion, if array.length == 1, the function won't call itself and instead
        // Just give rest = null
        if (array.length == 1) {
            list.value = array[array.length - 1];
            list.rest = null;
            return list;
        } else {
            // This is to continue the recursion.  If the array.length is not == 1, make the rest key to call arrayToList function
            list.value = array[0];
            // To avoid repetition, splice the array to make it smaller
            array.splice(0,1);
            list.rest = arrayToList(array);
            return list;
        }
    }
    
    
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```